# R plotly's ggplotly removing layers from ggplot2's geom_point

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly, geom-point

I'm creating the following fill, color, and size coded plot in `R`'s `ggplot2`'s `geom_point`:

Example dataset:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)
levels.mat <- matrix(data = runif(7*6, 1, 3), nrow = 7, ncol = 6, dimnames = list(paste0("I", 1:7), paste0("P", 1:6)))
scores.mat <- matrix(data = runif(7*6, 0, 10), nrow = 7, ncol = 6, dimnames = list(paste0("I", 1:7), paste0("P", 1:6)))
sig.mat <- matrix(data = sample(c(F, T), 7*6, replace = T), nrow = 7, ncol = 6, dimnames = list(paste0("I", 1:7), paste0("P", 1:6)))

df <- dplyr::left_join(reshape2::melt(levels.mat) %>% dplyr::rename(x = Var1, y = Var2, level = value),
                       reshape2::melt(scores.mat) %>% dplyr::rename(x = Var1, y = Var2, score = value)) %>%
  dplyr::left_join(reshape2::melt(sig.mat) %>% dplyr::rename(x = Var1, y = Var2, sig = value))
```

Plot:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y))+
  geom_point(aes(fill = level, size = score, color = sig),shape=21)+
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "lightgray", high = "darkred")+
  scale_color_manual(breaks = c(F, T), values = c("black", "green"))+
  theme_minimal() + theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust = 1))
```

Which gives:
[image]

If I wrap it with `plotly::ggplotly`:

```
plotly::ggplotly(ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y))+
  geom_point(aes(fill = level, size = score, color = sig),shape=21)+
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "lightgray", high = "darkred")+
  scale_color_manual(breaks = c(F, T), values = c("black", "green"))+
  theme_minimal() + theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust = 1)))
```

I get:
[image]

So the `fill` gradient seems to be gone and all points are filled with the same color.

I also get this warning message:

```
Warning messages:
1: In L$marker$color[idx] <- aes2plotly(data, params, "fill")[idx] :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
2: In L$marker$color[idx] <- aes2plotly(data, params, "fill")[idx] :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Here's my `seesionInfo`:

```
R version 4.2.3 (2023-03-15)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS 14.1.2

other attached packages:
 [1] plotly_4.10.1.9000  rmarkdown_2.21      shinyjs_2.1.0       ggplot2_3.4.2       readr_2.1.4         DT_0.28             Matrix_1.5-4.1      dplyr_1.1.2        
 [9] shiny_1.7.4         BiocManager_1.30.20
```

Comment: I directly copied your code and was not able to replicate the issue. The fill colors displayed as expected with no error message.

Comment: Thanks. You're referring to the `plotly::ggplotly` part, right?

Comment: Yes, the `plotly::ggplotly` part. I am using R version 4.1.2 on Linux (I should update, lol). I would suggest making sure your packages are updated.

Comment: You are right, it was a package(s) update thing.

Comment: Nice. I'm happy to help.